# Unable to read memory for object array deletion

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I am testing out some object arrays in C++, and I am trying to delete these objects afterwards, as I am supposed to.

But here's the problem: the deleteInputPattern variable works fine, so I am able to fully delete "inputs" within the CSVFile header class, but its equivalent in the main file, "inputArray",  triggers a breakpoint.

What is the problem here? Am I trying to delete non-existent memory? Do any of the pointers need

Code wall below:

### InputTest.h:

```
#pragma once
class InputTest
{
    private:
        float r;
        float g;
        float b;
        float t;
    public:
        InputTest();
        ~InputTest();
        InputTest(float r, float g, float b, float t);

        void setR(float newT);
        float getR();
        void setG(float newT);
        float getG();
        void setB(float newT);
        float getB();
        void setT(float newT);
        float getT();

        void print(int count);
};
```

### InputTest.cpp:

```
#include "InputTest.h"
#include <stdio.h>

InputTest::InputTest()
{
    printf("Input constructor\n");
}

InputTest::~InputTest()
{
    printf("Input destructor\n");
}

InputTest::InputTest(float r, float g, float b, float t)
{
    this->r = r;
    this->g = g;
    this->b = b;
    this->t = t;
}

void InputTest::setR(float newT)
{
    r = newT;
}

float InputTest::getR()
{
    return r;
}

void InputTest::setG(float newT)
{
    g = newT;
}

float InputTest::getG()
{
    return g;
}

void InputTest::setB(float newT)
{
    b = newT;
}

float InputTest::getB()
{
    return b;
}

void InputTest::setT(float newT)
{
    t = newT;
}

float InputTest::getT()
{
    return t;
}

void InputTest::print(int count)
{
    printf("R: %.2f\n", r);
    printf("G: %.2f\n", g);
    printf("B: %.2f\n", b);
    printf("T: %.2f\n", t);
}
```

### Copy.h:

```
#pragma once
class InputTest;

class Copy
{
    private:
        int patternCount;
        InputTest** inputs;

    public:
        Copy();
        ~Copy();

        InputTest* getInputPattern(int index);
        void addInputPattern(InputTest* in);
        void deleteInputPattern();
};
```

### Copy.cpp:

```
#include "Copy.h"
#include "InputTest.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Copy::Copy()
{
    printf("CSV File constructor\n");
    inputs = NULL;
    patternCount = 0;

    inputs = new InputTest*[3];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        inputs[i] = new InputTest();
    }
}

Copy::~Copy()
{
    printf("CSV File destructor\n");
}

InputTest * Copy::getInputPattern(int index)
{
    printf("input gotten: %d\n", index);
    return inputs[index];
}

void Copy::addInputPattern(InputTest * in)
{
    inputs[patternCount] = in;
    patternCount++;
    printf("input added: %d\n", patternCount);
}

void Copy::deleteInputPattern()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < patternCount; i++)
    {
        delete inputs[i];
    }
    delete inputs;
    inputs = NULL;
}
```

### main.cpp:

```
#include "Copy.h"
#include "InputTest.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    bool testResult = false;
    Copy *test = NULL;
    test = new Copy();

    InputTest **inputArray;
    inputArray = new InputTest*[3];
    int count;

    for (count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        inputArray[count] = new InputTest();

        inputArray[count]->setR(0.2f);
        inputArray[count]->setG(0.6f);
        inputArray[count]->setB(0.8f);
        inputArray[count]->setT(0.5f);

        test->addInputPattern(inputArray[count]);
        inputArray[count] = test->getInputPattern(count);
        printf("next\n");
    }

    for (count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        printf("round %d\n", count);
        printf("R: %f\n", inputArray[count]->getR());
        printf("G: %f\n", inputArray[count]->getG());
        printf("B: %f\n", inputArray[count]->getB());
        printf("T: %f\n", inputArray[count]->getT());
    }

    test->deleteInputPattern();

    for (count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        delete inputArray[count];
    }

    delete inputArray;
    delete test;
    inputArray = NULL;
    test = NULL;
    return testResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seem to be the problematic line:

```
test->deleteInputPattern();

for (count = 0; count < 3; count++)
{
    delete inputArray[count];
}
```

Since you have already deleted using `test->deleteInputPattern()`, that memory is freed. Now you are deleting the same objects (to which you are still holding a reference via inputArray) explicitly in main using `delete inputArray`. But that memory is already deleted in `deleteInputPattern` and hence you should be getting a memory access error.

You need to free any allocated memory only once. There is no need to do it again in main(). Either call deleteInputPattern or call delete explicitly in main, but not both. I can recommend 2 best practices:

1. Use smart pointers
2. The allocating module should delete the memory (this may not be applicable in many situations though such as factories)

Comment: I've deleted the offending for-loop, and it seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. would you mind marking the question correct?